# join six table is not working in php and mysql

Tags: mysql

[image: table data]

[image: table data]

[image: table data]

[image: table data]

[image: table data]

[image: table data]

I'm trying to join 6 tables and want to display `payperiod_sdesc`, `gross_pay`, `esi_employer_contribution`, `pf_employer_contribution` and `employerContribution`.

I tried it from my end but difficulty in joining . I tried with four table join but remaining two table I find it difficult

```
left join 
py_process_labour_welfare
on
py_pay_group.pg_code = py_process_labour_welfare.pg_code
```

this line of join is not working ......

```
select payperiod_sdesc,gross_pay,esi_employer_contribution,employerContribution 
from py_process_emp_status_approved
left join py_process_tds_pf_pt 
  on py_process_emp_status_approved.ou_code = py_process_tds_pf_pt.ou_code
left join py_pay_group
  on py_process_tds_pf_pt.pg_code = py_pay_group.pg_code
left join py_process_labour_welfare
  on py_pay_group.pg_code = py_process_labour_welfare.pg_code
left join py_pay_period
  on py_process_labour_welfare.payperiod_code = py_pay_period.payperiod_code
left join py_payroll_calendar 
  on py_pay_period.paycal_code = py_payroll_calendar.paycal_code
```

I have attached all six table image links.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Dennys Henry no errors ....but when executing the Query in phpmyadmin....it is just loading in yellow label

Comment: Try to work with alias so the query will be more easy to read, add those alias before the column you want to select so you are sure there is no ambiguity and check that each join are on the right value